# How to make first letter of a word having umlaut in Upper Case using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For making 1st letter of any word in Upper case, I am using below -

```
    var HVal = "SchON";
    HVal.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g,function(f){return f.toUpperCase();});
```

I get the correct output here as "Schon". However, this code does not work if my string contains umlaut vowel e.g. HVal = "SchÖN". the output here is "SchöN". How can I make this work for strings containing umlaut letters ?

Comment: The answer might be like  `var HVal = "SchON";
    HVal.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g,function(f){return f.toUpperCase();});`

Comment: "Note: JavaScript's regular expression engine defines a specific set of characters to be "word" characters. Any character not in that set is considered a word break. This set of characters is fairly limited: it consists solely of the Roman alphabet in both upper- and lower-case, decimal digits, and the underscore character. Accented characters, such as "é" or "ü" are, unfortunately, [treated as word breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)."

Comment: Why not [`_.capitalize(HVal)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#capitalize)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is

`var HVal = "SchÖN dasdNdsad";
    HVal.toLowerCase().replace(/(^[a-z])|(\s[a-z])/g,function(f){return f.toUpperCase();});`

Comment: `hello` will not be replaced in `SchÖN dasdNdsad:hello`

Comment: Technically it is `dasdNdsad:hello` is a single word, if you want to make it work for that case use `/(^[a-z])|(\s[a-z])|([:][a-z])/g`

Comment: If you want to work for any other special characters add the character before `:` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use can something like this

```js
var HVal = "SchÖN";
HVal=capitalize(HVal);
alert(HVal);

function capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```